# Рекурсия импортов в Python 3.7

Tags: python, рекурсия

Есть у меня три файла: Класс1 и Класс2, а так же некий запускатор.
Класс2 использует некоторый код из Класса1.
И тут сразу два вопроса. Стоит ли импортировать Класс1 в Класс2, если они оба в любом случае будут импортированы в запускатор? 
И если я импортирую Класс1 в Класс2 - наступит ли бесконечная рекурсия? умеет ли питон бороться с такими неприятностями?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никакой рекурсии тут нет.

Вариант 1.

```
  запускатор
     / \
    /   \
   /     \
класс1  класс2
```

Вариант 2.

```
  запускатор
     / \
    /   \
   /     \
класс1  класс2
          |
        класс1
```

Все. Никакой рекурсии нет. Вот если бы класс1 импортировал класс2, то можно было бы говорить о рекурсии.